# azure blob storage-Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: azure-storage

I'm using **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient** to get list of images from azure blob storage, but getting exception `"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"`. how can I resolve this exception .

My Code :

```
       var azureBlobStorageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureBlobStorageConnectionString"];

        var azureBlobContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureBlobContainerName"];

       // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
       CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureBlobStorageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client. 
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.

         CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(azureBlobContainerName);

        // Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
        var containerList = container.ListBlobs().ToList();

        ImagesUrls = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in containerList)
        {
            var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
            ImagesUrls.Add(blob.Uri.AbsolutePath);
        }
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why this isnt working? I too am experiencing a very similar issue where it shows error at container.ListBlobs();

I also happen to have over 10K blobs in my container.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Loop is Not Running Properly while it's closing before it get all data from service, Check it.

Comment: I'm getting error here :"var containerList = container.ListBlobs().ToList();"

Comment: Im also facing same issue

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Either the timeout is not enough to fetch the records or there is wrong container name.

**Cross-check the container name**

if container name is ok then

**replace**

```
var containerList = container.ListBlobs().ToList();
```

**to**

```
var containerList = container.ListBlobs(new BlobRequestOptions {Timeout = new TimeSpan(3,0,0) }).ToList();
```

**Note:**  Maximum Timeout is  hours and some minutes. approximately 14 minutes and Minimum Timeout is 1 sec.